# jquery table sorter sort issues

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Good evening all,

I'm trying to implement jquery table sorter, all seems fine and sorts by columns, however for some reason the date (default) column doesn't sort by the date format I'm using. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0]]} ); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

The date column is the first column and the dates are written in this format:
2 June 11
15 October 11 etc

In addition, from the above code, how would you disable the option to sort a particular column (column 6, which is the final column)? Can't for the life of me figure it out!

Failing this, I'm more than happy to use the date format as dd/mm/yyyy if it's easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this to disable sorting on 6th header:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    sortList: [[0,0]],
    // pass the headers argument
    headers: { 
        // assign the sixth column (we start counting zero) 
        5: { 
            // this is header 6 since the headers start at 0
            // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
            sorter: false 
        }, 
    } 
});
```

see [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html) for doc on this option

to sort those types of dates you might have to make your own sorting implementation because `tablesorter` doesn't know what a `date` is (in that format)

so you can add a date parser, as [explained in the doc](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html).

Comment: that shouldnt if u specify it to header 5 as you see in the above code

Comment: i have no idea. i can see that happening bc u did not post it anywhere, can you post it to jsfiddle and we can see the results?

Comment: your comments were commenting out things that they should not have. and learn how to use jsfiddle correctly its a good resource

Comment: Thanks Neal, very much appreciated. Had never heard of jsfiddle. Just got to try and figure out the dte situation now - will change the dates I use to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: it seems like the dates are sorting correctly on the fiddle tho.

Comment: @Motley yea. i see what you mean... i added a december date to the fiddle and it is not correct, you have to make a parser for the format you have now. also its always best to use the FULL YEAR for the year element and not just 11 or the sorter might not know what the year part is if u do it in the format of: `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: Hmmmm, when I reload on the above fiddle the dates don't sort correctly - June and September are around the wrong way...

Comment: yes i see that. see my above comment about a different date format

Comment: @Neal - yup, just noticed that. However for ease I think I will change the date to dd/mm/yyyy - messages crossed over there!

Comment: you might not need to parse the info if u use `dd/mm/yyyy` for that type the tablesorter might do it for you

Comment: @Neal - think I'll take you up on that - the above date format doesn't work (it gets Sept and Oct mixed up)

Comment: update my fiddle and show me (do your changes then click update, then send me the new link)

Comment: i see that. you can do `dd/mm/yyyy` because the tablesorter assumes it `mm/dd/yyy` so you need to make a parser for the way you want it: or just use `mm/dd/yyy` as in: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wSktX/

Comment: Hmmm. I need it to be dd/mm/yyyy as it needs to be UK. Time to start searching on how to construct the parser. Thanks again